# Use environment variable in Popen

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, environment-variables

I have an environment variable, let's say PATH, which I want to echo using Popen method. My first attempt would be to use os.environ as follows:

```
from  subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import os

x = Popen(['echo', os.environ["PATH"]], stdout=PIPE)
result = x.communicate()[0]
print result
```

and the output is as expected:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Unfortunately, my requirement is to pass environment variable's name to Popen as in the following snippet:

```
x = Popen(['echo', "$PATH", stdout=PIPE)
```

This is what I get in stdout instead of the variable content:

```
$PATH
```

I also tried to set env parameter in Popen but to no avail:

```
x = Popen(['echo', "$PATH", stdout=PIPE, env=os.environ)
```

Is there a way to call Popen method with $ sign and variable name so it can still be used as a variable in the child process?

Comment: `x = Popen(['echo $PATH'], shell=True)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm:)

Comment: What prevents you from using `os.environ['PATH']` instead of `$PATH`? Generally it is advisable to avoid using `shell=True`.

Comment: And why do you want to `echo` the variable, if you can directly access it from `os.environ`? This seems like an XY problem.

Comment: Just before calling Popen I have a function which saves the command in a log file. I used PATH just as an example but in my case, it is variable pointing to some binaries. It is a really long path that is why I prefer to save "$NAME/..." in my log and then use the same string with Popen.

Comment: Do not use `shell=True`. It is dangerous and can result in broken behavior and security bugs if the expansion of the var contains unexpected text such as spaces or shell metacharacters like semi-colon.

Comment: @KurtisRader While I fully agree with your statement, it wouldn't be sufficient to just do `os.environ[...]` and then blindly use that in a call to `Popen` either, as that is equally dangerous. Since environment variables are set from the outside, they should never be used directly without checking that they are correct/reasonable.

Comment: @liliscent  I think I found even better solution than the one you suggested. As @Kurtis pointed out using `shell=True` might be risky but the following meets the expectations: `Popen(['echo', os.path.expandvars("$PATH")])`